# XSS regular expression

Tags: regex, security, xss

What is an regular expression that can be used to determine if a string is an XSS (cross site scripting) security risk?

Comment: The context is that I need to determine if a code-generated string contains text that qualifies as Xss. I have seen some example on the web but I would like to know if anyone has a tried-and-proven regular express I can borrow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on the context in which that string is being used.

For instance, if the string is being printed out as part of an HTML page, then the special HTML characters `<`, `>`, `"`, and `'` can potentially be XSS risks.

If it's being passed around via JSON, then `'` and `"` could potentially be XSS risks.

If it's being included in SQL statements (which it really shouldn't be, at least not directly - use parameterized queries), then things like `;` and backticks may be an issue.

Et cetera.

Comment: It should be noted that even if you do all of this that XSS is still a problem.

Answer (score 3):

There can never be a bullet proof function to stop all of xss and a regular expression isn't the best choice.   XSS is highly dependent on where on the page and limiting charicters such as `"` `'` `<` `>` is a good start,  but by no means a comprehensive solution.  Even with stopping these characters there are **[MANY](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html)** other ways of exploiting XSS. To name a few there are malicious href's: `javascript:alert(/xss/)` and injection of event handlers: `onload=alert(/xss/)`,  nether of which will be stopped if you filter for the 4 characters listed.

[HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is made up of literally thousands of regular expressions,  and it gets bypassed all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Look for any unencoded `<` characters in html generated from user data. Without any `<` characters, there can be no nasty html injected into your site.

If you want to allow for user-generated formatting, then limit the allowed html to a subset. It's going to be impossible to check this with regular expressions, so I recommend a good html parser instead.

Comment: A standard way to enable user-generated formatting is to disable all tags (by html-encoding all the angle-brackets), then "adding back" the tags you wish to allow.  There likely are frameworks to do this already, as @marcog suggests, as it's a more difficult task than it originally might seem.

Comment: An even better option is to simply use formatting markup that isn't HTML - something like Markdown (what StackOverflow uses) or BBCode (if you prefer a tag-based system) lets you not have to worry about unsafe HTML tags.

Comment: @Amber You still have to be careful that the generated html is safe. When you have one things bouncing from function to function encoding/decoding/translating, slip-ups can be hard to find.

Comment: Things like Markdown etc. generally don't have the ability to generate things like `script` tags. So the flow would generally be 'strip all HTML special characters -> process markdown' - because the 'process markdown' step can't introduce any unsafe HTML, it simplifies the process a lot.